# How to debug urllib2 request that uses a basic authentication handler

Tags: python, debugging, urllib2, basic-authentication

I'm making a request using `urllib2` and the `HTTPBasicAuthHandler` like so:

```
import urllib2

theurl = 'http://someurl.com'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, theurl, username, password)

authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

params = "foo=bar"

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://someurl.com/somescript.cgi', params)

print response.info()
```

I'm currently getting a `httplib.BadStatusLine` exception when running this code. How could I go about debugging? Is there a way to see what the raw response is regardless of the unrecognized HTTP status code?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Have you tried setting the debug level in your own HTTP handler? Change your code to something like this:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> handler=urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)
>>> opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
>>> urllib2.install_opener(opener)
>>> resp=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read()
send: 'GET / HTTP/1.1
      Accept-Encoding: identity
      Host: www.google.com
      Connection: close
      User-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'
header: Date: Sat, 08 Oct 2011 17:25:52 GMT
header: Expires: -1
header: Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
... the remainder of the send / reply other than the data itself
```

So the three lines to prepend are:

```
handler=urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
... the rest of your urllib2 code...
```

That will show the raw HTTP send / reply cycle on stderr.

**Edit from comment**

Does this work?

```
... same code as above this line
opener=urllib2.build_opener(authhandler, urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))
... rest of your code
```

Comment: I did see a mention somewhere of the `debuglevel` parameter for `HTTPHandler`, but the site I'm communicating with needs basic authentication, and as far as I know `HTTPBasicAuthHandler` doesn't have a debug option. Is there anything else I can do? I have managed to find the cause of my problem (misformed parameters).

Comment: recall that the parameters to [urllib2.build_opener()](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.build_opener) is a list of chains. You can tag your debug http handler onto your auth handler... See example.

Comment: With `urllib2.build_opener(authhandler, urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))` I get debug output, but the auth handler doesn't work and I get a `401 unauthorised`. I've tried with the order of the handlers switched too (not sure if that would make any difference) and the behaviour was the same.

Comment: Also, common error: Many sites need the user name as `user=...` and password as `password=...` so you need to prepend those strings to the actual user and password.

Comment: Oops, my bad, it does seem to be working! I think I saw the first 401 response and didn't notice the resulting authentication. Thank you! It's authenticating correctly, and showing debug output.

Comment: how do i get the response that get printed into a variable ?

Comment: Note that for https, you need to change this to urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=1)

Comment: @dspeyer, thanks for this, ```HTTPSHandler``` works perfectly.