# How to dump http request in python

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I am using http in my application.

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, postdata)
```

Is possible to get dump of this request on client side (after this line) ?

I need exactly what is sent to server (TCP dump ?), so

```
POST url HTTP/version\r\nHeaderKey: HeaderValue\r\n....
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dump"?

Comment: do you want to dump in json format

Comment: Raw request (tcp dump ?) would be best

Comment: You might want to check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7698546/735204)

Comment: @EmmettJ.Butler +1. The request just needs to be read right, is it not?

Comment: @EmmettJ.Butler is it possible to modify this solution to get dump to variable not to stdout/stderr ? I mean without crazy stuff like capturing stdout.

Answer (score 2):

> Is possible to get dump of this request on client side (after this
>   line) ? I need exactly what is sent to server (TCP dump ?)

you are looking for a log at the tcp layer, but you haven't actually sent anything over the wire via tcp?

All you did was create a Request object.

If you were to send the request you created, you could enable debug in a handler and view headers/data both sent and received:

```
import httplib
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://example.com'
headers = {'HeaderKey': 'HeaderValue'}
data = urllib.urlencode({})
request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers, data=data)
handler = urllib2.HTTPHandler()
handler.set_http_debuglevel(1)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
response = opener.open(request)
response.read()
response.close()
```

ouput:

```
send: 'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nHost: example.com\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nHeaderkey: HeaderValue\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
[snip]
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly your output is stdout  and is caused by urllib library which just print it there after seeing, that debuglevel is set ? Is it possible to somehow overload this behaviour and don't print that to stdout and capture it by other means ?

Comment: hackily, yes... you could redirect stdout to StringIO and capture it.